# Openshift: Fail to start cloned app after creating it with --from-app option

Tags: java, jboss, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I successfully created a new application using the `--from-app` option, but it refuses to start. The creation process has completed without any error.

This is what I get when I execute `rhc app-start mobservicebkp`:

```
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/53a5f2845004467500000393/jbossews
```

Doing a ssh to the machine and running manually `ctl_app start jbossews --trace` I get:

```
An error occurred executing 'gear start' (exit code: 2)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/53a5f2845004467500000393/jbossews

/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1344:in `block in do_control_with_directory'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1134:in `process_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1307:in `do_control_with_directory'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1156:in `do_control'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1576:in `start_cartridge'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1468:in `block in start_gear'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:84:in `block in each_cartridge'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1140:in `block in process_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1138:in `each'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1138:in `process_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:82:in `each_cartridge'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1463:in `start_gear'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb:1472:in `start_gear'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-node-1.25.7/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/application_container.rb:477:in `start_gear'
/usr/bin/gear:481:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/usr/bin/gear:66:in `do_command'
/usr/bin/gear:476:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in `run_active_command'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:74:in `run!'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Is it possible that `create-app --from-app` has missed some alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out! I'm currently integrating this application with New Relic and I was wrongly setting `JAVA_OPTS_EXT` variable. The correct form is

```
JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-javaagent:"/var/lib/openshift/53aa229750044611fc0004bf/app-root/repo/newrelic/newrelic.jar"
```

and I was previously setting it without `-javaagent`. My bad.